# Webpack 4 how to require sources as separated chunks and load them on demand

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, import

I have noticed that when I am importing source in the old way, like this: `require('./my-script')` it injects the code of the script into the main bundle.js.

And when I am importing like this: `import('./my-script')`
it created a separate new file and I even can name it with:

```
import(/* name.js */ './my-script');
```

That is nice, but in the new way of using import instead of require - how can I send parameters to the imported function?

For example, in require I could do `require('./my-script')('something');`

However this cannot be achieved using **import**

How can I pass parameters to an imported function and make it as a separate chunk in webpack?

This is the my-script.js (for example only):

```
// my-script.js
module.exports = str => {
  return `${str} was returned`;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`import(name)`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) is used for code splitting (creating separate chunks) and will return a promise for the module's exports once the chunk has been retrieved asynchronously.

With your example, it can be used with something like the following:

```
import('./my-script').then(myScript => myScript.default('hello'))
```

The [Dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) section provides a more complete example and describes how `import()` is used for code splitting and here in [Magic Comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) are options listed which you can use to control how the chunk is created and when it's retrieved so you can tweak the user experience.